# Heuristic to integrate (or find all extrema of) a function

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization, computational-mathematics, numerical-optimization

I have a function $f:[0, T] \to [0, 1]$ which is expensive to evaluate and cannot be differentiated numerically. I am interested in computing
$$\int_0^Tdt \min\left(\frac{Df}{Dt}(t), 0\right) \,.$$

In general, this seems to be a difficult problem. However, as a physicist, I will be satisfied with an approximation.

$f$ has many local extrema but I have found that there is a timescale $\Delta t \ll T$ such that there is one extremum on an interval of length $\Delta t$. Because of the intensity in computing $f$, it is not practical to evaluate $f$ on the uniform grid $\{k\Delta t | k \in Z\}$. Does there exist a 'good' or optimal approach to determining the integral within some tolerance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $m_i$ to be the $i$-th local minimum (treating $f(T)$ as a local minimum if $f$ is decreasing at $T$) and $M_j$ to be the $j$-th local maximum (treating $f(0)$ as a local maximum if $f$ is decreasing at $0$). The integral you are attempting to compute is then equal to $$\sum_i^n m_i-\sum_j^N M_j,$$ directly from applying the fundamental theorem of calculus to each monotone segment.

If computing a numeric derivative really is cost prohibitive, I would attempt to estimate the **mean** values for the local **minima** and **maxima**, along with an estimate for their respective **counts**. Stochastic integration doesn't afford the same guaranteed tolerances of standard techniques, but you can at least have guarantees in the limit assuming some nice distribution of $f$ (analogous to assuming some high-order derivative behaves nicely with classical numeric integration).

Comment: The derivative is computable numerically by using finite differences. In this case what approach would you try?

Comment: I'd be nervous using finite differences. The loss of precision happens at the subtraction step, and if your function varies as much as you're describing that could cause problems. The strategy is similar though: sample the derivative (or the **min** function you use) at various places and use that sampling to estimate its mean, hence the integral. More advanced methods would use past queries to focus future efforts on places where the derivative seems to be changing quickly. For the differentiation, check this out https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2013/10/14/complex-step-differentiation/

Comment: That's an interesting way to differentiate a function numerically; surprised I never saw it in my complex analysis class! Unfortunately, the function I'm working with is not analytic and cannot be extended to the complex plane. Also, experimentalists would not be able to use the approach since the parameter t is time.

Any particular advanced method you had in mind for sampling? While the algorithm for estimating the mean min and max value is clear to me. How would you go about estimating their counts?